# Define separate file for org-custom variables

Tags: org-mode, customize

I would like to create more separation between the custom variables generated through the Customize UI that are generated for org-mode, and non-org mode features.

I have already broken out my primary custom file, but I don't want this to contain anything related to org-mode.

I know I can do this manually, but I couldn't find a variable that would send these customizations to a separate file.

Comment: I don't think there is anything built-in to do that: you (or somebody else) would have to build it.

Comment: You can request that Org mode provide such a construct. To request an enhancement, use `M-x report-emacs-bug`.